# Automake/autoconf configuration to install as SUID

Tags: makefile, autotools, automake, gnu-make

Is there a way to configure a binary to be installed as "SUID" using automake/autoconf?
Is there any magick that can lead a `make install` to set the suid bit of a given binary target?

NOTE:
  I am running a "fakerooted" `make install` inside a script to create a tar file.

I tried:

```
# Makefile.am

bin_PROGRAMS = my_bin

#...

install-exec-hook:
    echo    "#### Setting SUID for my_bin. ####"
    ls -l $(DESTDIR)$(bindir)/my_bin
    chmod 4755 $(DESTDIR)$(bindir)/my_bin
    ls -l $(DESTDIR)$(bindir)/my_bin
    echo    "####-------------------------------####"
```

But with no success.

During `make install` I see:

```
#### Setting SUID for sudo_script. ####
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 8704 Mar 28 13:30 /install.pak/usr/bin/my_bin
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 8704 Mar 28 13:30 /install.pak/usr/bin/my_bin
####-------------------------------####
```

So one could think it is a problem with `fakeroot`, but if I move the `chmod` out of `Makefile.am` to my packaging script, it works. This is enough to convince me `fakeroot` is doing its job.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GAHH!!

Someone unconsciously put in my script, after `$FAKEROOT make install`:

```
$FAKEROOT chmod 755 $PAK_DIR/usr/bin/*
```

replacing all the permissions writen by `make install`.

Removing this line the `install-exec-hook` works as expected and the SUID bit is preserved...

(Were did I put my ax?...)

Comment: Your axe is over there, behind you, to the left, and under the bag containing the dynamite!